# Very New to Apps Script, question about why variable isn't showing up

Tags: google-apps-script

I am very new to programming in general, but excited about what I've been able to do so far for work projects. I'm wondering why in the program below, the variable companyID is not populating into the template literal string. I've tried putting it inside and outside the loop, and while I am not getting an error message, it just comes out as a space.

````
  let activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('foreachloop');
  let range = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 5, 4);
  let values = range.getValues();

//FOR EACH LOOP

values.forEach(function(value, index){
  
let companyID = activeSheet.getRange(1, 9).getValue();

if (index ===0) return;
let descriptionVariable = `Employee Number ${companyID} ${value[0]} ${value[1]} has a current status of ${value[2]}`

activeSheet.getRange(index + 1, 4).setValue(descriptionVariable);

})
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try it this way:

```
function lfunko() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('foreachloop');
  const values = sh.getRange(1, 1, 5, 4).getValues();
  const companyID = sh.getRange(1, 9).getValue();
  values.forEach(function (value, index) {
    if (index > 0) {
      sh.getRange(index + 1, 4).setValue(`Employee Number ${companyID} ${value[0]} ${value[1]} has a current status of ${value[2]}`);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This works even better!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. check your runtime environment. It must be set to V8 if you want to use this feature. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime
2. check the content of the cell you are pulling `companyID` from. Is it empty? You can `console.log(companyID)` or run a debugger to check

Comment: I am a huge idiot and spent all my time writing the program and none of my time checking the correct row/column. I got it to work!

Comment: @ChrisPBacon thanks for accepting my answer point 2. then :)